# OS pod install error. Module glog cannot be installed

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I'am trying to upgrade "react-native" from "0.50.4" to "0.55".

When I run pod install, i receive an error

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/local/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/local/bin/gmkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... no
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc...  -arch armv7 -isysroot 
checking whether the C compiler works... no
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
/Users/MacBook/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/glog/0.3.4-1de0b/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/MacBook/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/glog/0.3.4-1de0b/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/MacBook/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/glog/0.3.4-1de0b':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `8.0` on target `quanta_react` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

I am a beginner in react-native and I can not make a pod install in my iOS project.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you maybe post the config.log please? And just in case, did you already run pod init? :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Most of the times this happens when you have more then one Xcode development version. Well thats what happened to me. You can try re-configuring/changing the xcode-select path to default Xcode.app:

Check your Xcode app name first

```
xcode-select -p
```

If its not Xcode.app then do this:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

after that run pod install again

If its already set to Xcode.app then try following:

```
cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-* ../../scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh
```

i didn't need to do that because the step before worked already, maybe it helps you :)

Comment: As a follow up -- if you have a space in the name of your xcode path like `/Applications/Xcode 9.4.1`, remove it (eg `/Applications/Xcode9.4.1`), as this could also cause issues with the C compiler.

Comment: running ios-configure-glog.sh and going to the end needs sudo in my case (if run without sudo, I get compiler can't create executables).  is there something I can change with my environments?

Answer (score 18):

I'm promoting Chase Holland's comment to an answer, because it solved my problem: remove any spaces you may have in your Xcode path.

`/Applications/Xcode 10.0.app`: will cause the error above

`/Applications/Xcode10.0.app`: will not

Comment: Has it really been 3 years and FB still hasn't fixed this? Removing spaces did it for me. And yes I had to rename my Xcode app name so there were no spaces.

Comment: This did it for me as well. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 2):

Just restart my mac, it worked for me.

Comment: That was so easy after 2 hrs of hard work.

Answer (score 1):

try this below command.
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still experiencing issue with glog 0.3.4, adding below line to the Podfile might help. It looks like glog can be stuck on the older version while actually pods are installing newer one.

```
pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename your Xcode app name, make sure the app name does not include space character.(Xcode 11.app to Xcode11.app)

Then switch to the Xcode with **sudo xcode-select --switch**

sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode11.app/

Then, perform pod install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but for a different reason and none of the above worked for me. After a lot of digging around, I found out that having installed `coreutils`, `moreutils` and `gnu-sed` and set them up to override the mac osx shipped utilities was the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error would be caused by installing another version of xcode. So after installing the new version restart your system and run pod install again it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In my mac mini (m1 chip) I have solved this problem by installing pod using this command "arch -x86_64 pod install".

Comment: Was it necessary to use Rosetta? Why?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33111273)